# HtmlAgilityPack Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack and i am facing this error

```
Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.
```

using this code

```
    Document.LoadHtml(textBox1.Text);

    var result = Document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("id('side_info')/x:div[2]/x:a/x:span");
    textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
```

[NOTE] i am using XPath Checker add on for Firefox and it tells that the namespace x is at uri http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/

But i cant add the name space to the HtmlAgilityPack SelectNodes

Comment: how about posting the html code?

Comment: How about telling me how to fix that problem in general because the html code is too big ?

Comment: Also i tryied to remove the name space x and use the XPath without it. it works in the firefox Addon XPath checker but when it comes to my code it tells me the object reference error

Answer (score -9):

Ok i solved that problem with SelectSingleNode and XSLTContext.

Comment: "solved with" these two things, you say? but what did you do to solve it?